# Sublime Text C plugin - code templates and autocomplete

Tags: c, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublimetext-snippet

I'm looking for a plugin (or a way to create metadata for a plugin) that will allow me to do the following with Sublime Text 3 for the C programming language.

1. Generate C source file from a template
2. (Auto) generate C style function comments

For the plugin I am looking for something that handles autocompletion with argument hints (similar to the hover-box hints in VS indicating what the parameter is. I am aware that this may require some bit of coupling to the documentation of the function in a function block.

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit of others, here's the workaround I ended up working with and the rationale

1. For C sourcefile generation, I ended up using eclipse CDT as it comes with the feature pretty much out of the box under templates.
2. For comment generation I also used eclipse CDT templates bound to hotkeys. It is somewhat limited (the auto-population of function name and parameters only gets picked up if the hotkey is triggered inside the scope of the function), but it works also pretty much out of the box.